# Error when trying to find main window handle of active/focused window

Tags: c#

What i want to do:

Get the processName of the current app that is active/focused, but here's the problem, some programs like google chrome have multiple child windows at the same time, when i run this code i get an exception that states that there were multiple id's found, etc.

Here's the code:

Essentials to get the code running

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

And here's the main code:

```
 Process myProcess = Process.GetProcesses().Single(
p => p.Id != 0 && p.MainWindowHandle == GetForegroundWindow());
```

When run, if the app has multiple child windows, i get an exception, what should i do?

Comment: Never iterate the GetProcessses() return value, dragons live there.  Pinvoke GetWindowThreadProcessId() instead so you can go straight from the window to the one-and-only Process.GetProcessById().

Comment: GetWindowThreadProcessId() is worthless, it get's the wrong pID of any program, how is that useful? notepad pID is 6538 (for example), your suggestion returns me 6724, so how the f am i supposed to use the wrong ID? your recommendation is worthless

Comment: Thanks for the compliment.  Clearly you incorrectly used the thread ID it returns, not the process ID.